# nGinx Rewrite Issue exclusion

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am attempting to rewrite my `/support` url, so I can grab the "page" as an appended querystring.

The issue I am running into now, is my `assets` are also contained in the `/support` subfolder, so they too are getting re-written.

How can I change this to exclude my assets? (where assets = /support/assets/styles, /support/assets/scripts, etc...)

Here is my current `location` block

```
location /support/ {
    index index.php;
    rewrite ^/support/(.*) /support/index.php?_p=$1 last;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /support/index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: You should just add another location, `location /support/assets/ { alias <asset folder path>; }`

Comment: `/support/assets/` is my `<asset folder path>`

Comment: that's ok you can see that path inside too. url location and folder path are two different things. Even if they are same you need to provide it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the assets with `try_files` before performing the `rewrite` by using a named `location`.

For example:

```
location /support/ {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/support/(.*) /support/index.php?_p=$1 last;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.